# How to loop through array when user select which element to see Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, while-loop

What I want to do is have the user type a number and based on the number they type it displays the corresponding element in the array but using a while loop and concatenating the results of the loop. I tried creating a while loop that runs while the variable is greater than or equal to the minimum array value. But I'm having a lot of issues trying to make all of these things work.

```
  Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p>Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>
     function myFunction() {
         var x = document.getElementById("myText");
         var currentVal = x.value;
         var jobs = ["Best Buy", "Staples", "Macys", "Dunkin Donuts", "Legal Aid"];
         var i = jobs.length - 1;
         while (jobs.length >= i) {
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jobs[i] + "&nbsp";
             break;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Why is HTML combined with JS?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myText");
var demo  = document.getElementById("demo");
var jobs  = ["Best Buy","Staples","Macys","Dunkin Donuts","Legal Aid"];

function myFunction() {
  // Get val from array or fallback to empty String
  demo.innerHTML = jobs[this.value] || ""; 
}

input.addEventListener("input", myFunction);
```

```html
"What I want to do is have the user type a number
and based on the number they type it displays
the corresponding element"<br>


Type your Number: <input type="text" id="myText" value="">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

---

If you want the user to enter the number of items to be returned (starting from the first array key):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myText");
var demo  = document.getElementById("demo");
var jobs  = ["Best Buy","Staples","Macys","Dunkin Donuts","Legal Aid"];

function myFunction() {
  // Get val from array or fallback to empty String
  demo.innerHTML = jobs.slice(0, this.value).join("<br>");
}

input.addEventListener("input", myFunction);
```

```html
"What I want to do is have the user type a number
and based on the number get as much items from the Array"<br>


Number of items: <input type="text" id="myText" value="">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This is great, I was just wondering how to do this with a while loop also if the user types 2 it would show the first 2 jobs or 3 then the first 3 jobs.

Comment: @LazerStackr that's not stated inside your question. Sorry. You might want to try something your self and ask a brand-new question?

Comment: okay how about just using a while loop to reach the same effect

Comment: @LazerStackr I don't see how a while loop would work in this case - of your exact question - Get an array item depending on the number entered in the field.

Comment: function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    
    var jobs = [" BestBuy"," Staples"," Macys"," Dunkin Donuts","Legal Aid"];
    var y = x -1;
    var r = " ";
    //without quotes makes undefined string 
 
 while(y>=0){
 //cat
        r = r+jobs[y];
 //print
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = r;
y--;
}


}
Got it! thanks

Comment: @LazerStackr I see no purpose of defining all over again your initial Array inside that function. Also your var `y` is unnecessary :) you've could used  your var `x` value like while(x > -1) ... NVM, `.slice()` and `.join()` are much simpler but seems like you really like that `while` :) Glad you got it.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is have the user type a number and based on the
>   number they type it displays the corresponding element in the array
>   but using a while loop and concatenating the results of the loop.

Try substituting `input type="number"` element for `input type="text"` element ; `onchange` event ; substitute `+=` operator for `while` loop to concatenate `.innerHTML` of element with `id` `demo` , `Array.prototype.splice()`

```html
Name:
<input type="number" min="0" max="4" id="myText" value="Mickey">
<p id="demo"></p>
<p>Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("myText"),
    demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
    jobs = ["Best Buy", "Staples", "Macys", "Dunkin Donuts", "Legal Aid"];

  function myFunction() {
    var val = jobs.splice(this.value, 1);
    demo.innerHTML += val + "&nbsp";
  }

  x.onchange = myFunction; x.focus();
  
</script>
```